# Haskell Rewriting Min Class

Tags: function, class, haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell and I'm writing a function that is similar to min instead of just accepting 2 values it'll accept 3. I've worked out the class as shown here:

```
min3 :: a -> a -> a -> a
```

However what would I put with the function itself  after writing how many input variables?

```
min3 x y z =
```

This is probably stupidly easy and I'm missing something but if you could please help me out I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: `min3 x y z = min (min x y) z`

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One implementation

```
min3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
min3 x y z = min x $ min y z
```

Notes:

- In the type definition you have to write `Ord a => ...` because your arguments shall be ordable, i.e. the `min` function has to be defined for them.

@Lee provides a point free implementation which also can be written as

import Data.Composition ((.:))

```
min3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
min3 =  min .: min
```

Note: `f .: g` is a shortcut for `(f .) . g` which is defined in [Data.Composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html#v%3a.%3a)

Answer (score 5):

You can also write it as:

```
min3 :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
min3 = ((min .) .) min
```

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation:

```
min3 x y z = head $ sort [x,y,z]
```

And this could be easily generated to a function that can find the minimum in a list:

```
minimum = head . sort
```

`Data.List` gives [a different implementation of `minimum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#minimum).

Comment: Don't you have to write ``minimum = head . sort``?

Comment: @tampis Oops, fixed.  Thank you.