# Error in ghci which I cannot reproduce in written haskell file

Tags: haskell, ghci, runhaskell

I tried to check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836320/haskell-rewriting-min-class#22837528) with ghci and get the following error:

```
> import Data.List
> let m = head . sort
> m [2,3,4]

<interactive>:5:4:
   No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal `2'
   Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
   In the expression: 2
   In the first argument of `m', namely `[2, 3, 4]'
   In the expression: m [2, 3, 4]
```

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error in a written haskell file:

```
-- file.hs
import Data.List

main = do
    let m = head . sort
    putStrLn $ show $ m [2,3,4]
```

Running this file with `runhaskell file.hs` gives me the expected value `2`. What is my mistake in the ghci session?

**Edit:** I noted, that the function `m` has a weird type in ghci:

```
> import Data.List
> let m = head . sort
> :t m
m :: [()] -> ()
```

Why is this the case? Shouldn't it has the type `Ord a => [a] -> a`? For `sort` and `head` I get the expected types:

```
> :t sort
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
> :t head
head :: [a] -> a
```

Comment: The dreaded monomorhism restriction strikes again. Try doing a `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` before running your code in ghci.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the fault of the dreaded Monomorphism restriction.  Basically, because you didn't specify a type for `m`, GHCi guesses it for you.  In this case, it guesses that `m` should have the type `[()] -> ()`, even though that is clearly not what you want.  Just give `m` a type signature in `GHCi` and you'll be fine.

```
> :set +m  -- multiline expressions, they're handy
> let m :: Ord a => [a] -> a
|     m = head . sort
```

You can disable the Monomorphism restriction with

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

But it's usually pretty handy, otherwise you have to specify lots of types for things that you normally wouldn't in interactive mode.

Comment: Can you explain, why ghci guesses ``[()] -> ()``?

Comment: Basically, because it's the "simplest" type which satisfies the constraints imposed by Ord a => [a] -> a.